# Is it with Codemagic possible to have multiple codemagic.yaml files?

Tags: cicd, codemagic

I'm using Codemagic for my Flutter CI. For my repo, I'm using a monorepo structure. So I split my repository into +20 local packages. For every package, I'm running an own workflow (analyze, test, format, etc.).

Because of the high number of packages, becomes the [codemagic.yaml](https://docs.codemagic.io/yaml/yaml-getting-started/) to a massive file and the readability decreases.

With GitHub Actions, I'm able to split my workflows into multiple files, which increases the readability a lot (for every package a single file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the Codemagic Team an got this answer:

> Unfortunately we do not plan on introducing the feature to split configurations into multiple different files at this point.
>
> [But] there’s a couple of things you could look at doing. Firstly, take a look into using YAML anchors and aliases so you don’t repeat scripts. Here’s a [guide](https://blog.codemagic.io/what-you-can-do-with-yaml/#:%7E:text=okay%20with%20this.-,5.%20Don%E2%80%99t%20repeat%20yourself,-When%20we%20run) and a sample codemagic.yaml.
> The other option is to use the Codemagic REST API to trigger your builds and pass app specific environment variables for the build. In this was you can has a single workflow which you pass the variables too. See more about the API [here](https://docs.codemagic.io/rest-api/codemagic-rest-api/).
> There’s a few script samples [here](https://github.com/codemagic-ci-cd/codemagic-sample-projects/tree/main/white-label-api-scripts) that show how to call it, and this yaml shows where the environment variables are overwritten.

Source: https://codemagicio.slack.com/archives/CEKE2KZ37/p1645538193515549?thread_ts=1645537597.216489&cid=CEKE2KZ37